# hover panel not shown on first result item in people search result

Tags: 2013, people-search

When i key in a search keyword and give a people search.

I am seeing a couple of people results.

But on the first result item i am not able to see the hover panel when i hover over that item.

same is the case when move to other pages of the result. Only for the first item the hover panel is missing.

screen shot when mouse hovered on the first result:
[image]
screen shot when mouse hovered over the second result item:
[image]

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but since Google lead me here, maybe it can help others: 
I had this issue, too, and in my case it turns out the hover panel for the first element had not enough free space to render.
So I added some css to the page of the search results and now also the first search result get the hover panel.

5 px top padding did the job:

```
<style>.ms-srch-group-content{padding-top: 5px;}</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2e7b999c-cae9-4978-8f87-9b85210e5e23/people-search-not-showing-data?forum=sharepointsearch) answer posted in MSDN blog may help you

Comment: please read the question and reply. here the question is for not showing the hover panel. and you give a link for post which says an error message shown in the same hover panel.