# Error on hover panel of people search result "We weren't able to find additional information"

Tags: 2013, people-search

In people search result while hovering over all result item, in the hover panel in the middle I can see a message "We weren't able to find additional information".

I saw a msdn post for the same question in this [MSDN Link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2e7b999c-cae9-4978-8f87-9b85210e5e23/people-search-not-showing-data?forum=sharepointsearch)

but there it is said that "If the person has no authored documents, then it will display this in the hover panel: We weren't able to find additional information."

But for my case the authored document is also shown.

Please find in the screen shot below marked in red:

[image]

Also to mention this not a duplicate question of another question which i have posted earlier - one says hover panel is not shown for first result item and another says in the shown hover panel an error message is shown.
Please find the link of the other question - [Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115767/hover-panel-not-shown-on-first-result-item-in-people-search-result/115781#115781)

Did I missed something?

Comment: @mike please read the query again and remove the duplicate tag as both are different functionality issues. one is for not showing the hover panel and another is for showing an error message in the hover panel. The only similarity is that both are asked by me and on the same day. Also the answer received is different from my query.

Answer (score 0):

If this profile account has not authored or subscribed to any content, you will see this message. If you have custom properties stored in user profile and you want to show on hover panel, you have to edit the hover panel java script.